# How to find an callinstr is calling uesr-defined function?

Tags: llvm

I am writing some pass using LLVM. I recognize all CallInst in functions using

```
bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
    for (Function::iterator BB = F.begin(), E = F.end(); BB != E; BB++) {
        for (BasicBlock::iterator BI = BB->begin(), BE = BB->end(); BI != BE; BI++) {
            if (isa<CallInst>(&(*BI))) {
                CallInst *CI = dyn_cast<CallInst>(BI);
                // TODO: 
             }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, I want to check if the called function is defined by user because I want to focus on such Instruction. Could u get me some advice?

Comment: Or if I could write two extra pass in sequence to save information?

Comment: CallInst::getCalledFunction() returns the function, if available. Whether that is user defined is another matter. I don't even understand what it means for a function to be user defined.